# Including the Same Form in Multiple Webpages

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a simple form saved in a MySQL table on website A.

I need to be able to post that same form on websites B, C, D, E... etc. None of these websites are hosted on the same server as website A. When the form is updated, the form on the rest of the websites must also update.

I've tried creating a page on website A which queries the database and displays the form. Then on website B, including the page. I get the following error:

> Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server
>   configuration by allow_url_include=0

I know that allow_url_include is probably turned off by most webhosts, so I need a way to circumvent this and safely include my form. Is the solution to use AJAX or Javascript? Could you give pointers on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Would using an IFRAME be an acceptable solution? Anything beyond that is going to cause you a lot of problems because of security concerns. Not impossible, but might not be worth the extra work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all AJAX is done by using javascript, so if you use AJAX you'll be using javascript.

Then, there's no way to do this by embedding the form directly in the html. What I would suggest is:

- Create a web service that returns the list of fields that you want to include in your form.
- Create a js script that builds the form dynamically based on the info returned by the service.
- Create function in your web service that receives the information from the form or try to submit the form directly to the url you want (I don't remember if that would work)
- Use that script in all of your pages.

Hope it helps.

Comment: if the js is : `var t="<form>.....</form>"` and on site 2, where he wants to put the form he can do `<script src="site1"></script><script> document.write(t);</script>`

Comment: Yeah he could do that as well. In both cases he might need to update something manually, but at least it's only in one place.

Comment: var t="<form>.....</form>" <script src="site1"></script><script> document.write(t);</script
So to implement this, basically I would be saving the table into a javascript variable on site A, then calling that script on site B? That seems quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

If your form lives in a MySQL database, then it's not accurate to say it is "saved on website A". Whatever server-side code you have in website A probably connects to the MySQL database on **localhost** port 3306 to retrieve the form.

Code from websites B-E can also connect to MySQL on port 3306 of **Server** A, if that port is open and there is a MySQL user that can connect remotely. If all servers are in the same private network, that's probably ok. If not, it is a security risk to open the MySQL port to the world. You could limit connections to port 3306 on Server A to only Servers B-E using a firewall. Or, you could write a simple web service on Server A, that when called via HTTP fetches the form from MySQL and returns the form HTML, which you could call asynchronously from Servers B-E.

Comment: from the question **None of these websites are hosted on the same server as website A** Usually DBs on shared hosting do not allow remote access.

Comment: who said anything about shared hosting?

Comment: +1 for a clear and correct answer. @ItayMoav-Malimovka - AFAIK, GoDaddy has an option to enable remote access.

Comment: @carillonator read the question again, it is **strongly** implied there.

Answer (score -1):

U can use the following ways, u will need to learn them as this is not the place to write a tutorial:

1. use curl/file_get_contents to get the HTML using on the **server** side.
2. use `<script>` tags on the **client** side to include a file from the server you host the form
3. use **Iframe**